# 2nd layout Button is not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

This is my First Question & I'm a new android learner,

Suddenly in my ellipse 2nd layout button is not working;
after pressing button of my first layout it working & going to second layout.

But in 2nd layout my Button is not working, I tested it very simple code. Please check

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button b1,b2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2); Need to   remove
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class));
        }

    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

This is my 2nd activity code

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {
EditText ed;
Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
    ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button21);

    button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
        }

    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity2, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to find "R.id.button21" or is that a typo?
Could you also post your layout files?

Comment: There is no click event associated to `b2`

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. You want to show two layout in one activity or in two different activity?

Comment: I just try to user the button on my second layout.@DerGolem
I'm finding the ID of button@Lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You are simply changing the layout on first activity using setContentView(). You are not navigating from one activity to another.
Either you can register the button of layout 2 by onClicklistener after setting it on activity.

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2); 
             button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button21);
             button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Working",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         

}
    });              
        }
    });


or you can goto your other activity 

b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2); remove
          startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class));
    }

});
```